# We are given the digits $1,2,4,5,6,7,9$. How many even, $4$-digit numbers, bigger than $5000$, with distinct digits can we form?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I was solving some exercises and I would like to hear your opinion about this.

> Question 1 : We are given the  digits $1,2,4,5,6,7,9$.  How many even, $4$-digit numbers, bigger than $5000$, with distinct digits can we form?

**What I did** :

*Step 1*: It is Combinations nCr, with formula  $nCr = C(n,r) = \frac{n!}{r!(n - r)!}$.  The order doesn't matter and replacement  not allowed-cause it says needs only 1 time to be used each digit.

*Step 2*: I have $7$ digits ($1,2,4,5,6,7,9$). I have to chose $4$ digits so the $r=4$.

*Step 3*:  How to create **even** numbers? the digit $4$ with digit $2$ if I add them (+) it makes $6$, (I can't use the digit $4$ and $2$).  The digit $7 + 1$ makes $8$, (so those digits can't be used again).  Now I add $5 + 6 + 9= 20$, so I have $6820$, my $4$ digits.

*Step 4*: I check if $5000 < 6820$.  It is true.

*Step 5*: Now I am not sure if  $n=6820$? and $r=4$. If that is true,
\begin{align*}
C(n,r) & = C(6820,4)\\
& = \frac{6820!}{4!(6820−4)!}\\
& = \frac{6820!}{4!6816!}
\end{align*}

Comment: Picking an even number means the units digit must be an even number.  In this case, it must be $2, 4$, or $6$.  The importance of the fact that the number must be at least $5000$ is that if you pick $2$ or $4$, you still have four choices for the thousands digit.  On the other hand, if you pick $6$, you have three choices for the thousands digit since you can no longer choose $6$.  This problem required the use of the [Multiplication Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) and the [Addition Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_sum), nothing more.

Comment: The comment of @N.F.Taussig nailed it.  Unsure, from your posting, whether you already also realize the following: 
 The other thing to consider is that in general, you are interested in permutations, not combinations.  For example, consider the simpler question of how many $3$ digit numbers can be constructed by choosing $3$ numbers, without replacement, from the set $\{1,2,3,4,5\}.$  The answer is $$\frac{5!}{(5-2)!}~~\text{rather than} ~~\frac{5!}{[(5-2)!] \times [2!]}.$$

Comment: @user2661923  In this case, the constraints that the number is even and larger than $5000$ means we have to use the Multiplication and Addition Principles, not permutations.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I agree.  However, it is unclear whether the OP (i.e. original poster) understands this.  Permutations may be considered to be an application of the Multiplication principle, where there are no constraints.  I did think that it was important to emphasize that in the simpler problem that I posed, the enumeration is $(20)$, rather than $(10)$.  It is unclear whether the OP realizes this.

Comment: Guys , I follow your comments.  If it was saying WITH replacement then I must use the 5!/((5-2!)*2!) ?

Comment: @Yun.kon  Here is a strategy for doing the problem:  Choose the units digit, which must be even.  Depending on the choice of units digit (see my first comment), determine how many choices you have for the thousands digit, how many choices you have for the hundreds digit, and how many choices you have for the tens digit.  For each case, multiply to determine the number of choices.  Add the results for each case.

Comment: Choose the units digit, which must be even -> 2 and 6. determine how many choices you have for the thousands digit -> If you mean the 5 digit-> It must be $10^{5}$ the total choices.  how many choices you have for the hundreds digit ->  not sure about this

Comment: 1000 ->digit 4 , digit 3 ->100 and digit 2 -> 10 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A neat way to do it is to realize that

- Whichever way you choose other digits, there will be $(5\cdot4)=20$ ways to fill the two middle digits
- You can't have $6$ at both the thousands and units place, so
  ways of filling these digits would be $[(4\cdot3)-1] = 11$

Multiply the two

Comment: Multiply the two,means 20ways of fill the two middle digits and 11 I found the other so it would be 20*11 right?also why you -1 from here (4⋅3)−1]=11?

Comment: Because you can't have a number like 6 x x 6 , since only one $6$ is available

Comment: thank you for your answer

Comment: Glad to be of help :)